# When area learning in Project Tango SDK's examples are running, where is the learning data stored?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, tango

I have using Phap 2 pro for my graduation project.
The project theme is 3D object recognition using Google Tango.
So, I run the area learning in Project Tango SDK's example! 
I need the area learning data!
However, I can't find it.

Where is the learning data stored?

[Area description picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDFpA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find where ADF is stored from Google's document.
I think there is no specific path to ADF.

But we can export ADF to any path by using **areaDescription.ExportToFile(string filePath)**

---

How to use :

```
AreaDescription m_areaDescription = AreaDescription.ForUUID(string UUID);
m_areaDescription.ExportToFile(Application.persistentDataPath);
```

[reference](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/area-description)

UUID is an unique ID allocated to each ADF. In your picture, small size string like "7ad2e08e-..." is the UUID.

ADF is a binary file. So you can't use this outside a Tango application. If you want a captured mesh data, maybe **ExperimentalMeshBuilderWithColor** scene can be helpful.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I personally never managed to get into Area Description Files, but looking at your question here are two facts that came to my mind:

- The A of ADF is for Area... so I am not sure that the learnt data can help to recognize objects (except maybe for some key points)
- PTC (Vuforia) recently came out with 3D objects recognition in their SDK (if you haven't checked it out already, their demo is pretty cool)